# Não satisfaz a condição com o valor informado pelo usuário

Tags: python

Fiz esse código, porém ele não entra na opção informada pelo usuário (acho que as opção já diz o que ele tem que fazer).

```
lista = []
while True:
    print("Adicionar nome - 1")
    print("Sair - 0")
    print("Listar - 2")
    op = input()

    if op == 0:
        break
    elif op == 1:
        nome = input("Digite o nome")
        lista.append(nome)
    elif op == 2:
        j = 0
        for nomes in lista:
            print(nomes)
```

Comment: Defina o tipo de entrada para o input. Isso resolverá o seu problema:  op = int(input())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A entrada `input()` faz com que o usuário digite uma string, por esse motivo, quando você compara `op == 0` você está comparando uma string com um inteiro. Para solucionar isso você possui 2 opções:

1ª:

```
op = input()
if op == '0':
   break
```

2ª: Utilizar `int(input())` para receber um inteiro

```
op = int(input())
if op == 0:
   break
```

Comment: muito obrigado!